# Is there a way to speed up the "security disagreement" with the USA in succubox?

Tags: succubox

I'm at the point where I'm just waiting for the "security disagreement" with the USA to get to 100%, is there a way I can speed it up?

Comment: If you think conquering the US is slow, wait until you get to The Rest Of Asia...

Answer (score 3):

The "Security Disagreement" progress is tied to how many employees you have assigned to "Security", if you wish to get to 100% faster you need to allocate more employees there.  Do note however that the more you allocate the more it will cost, so you'll need to put a sizable part of your workforce on actually working to earn the money necessary to pay for the effort.

Comment: Is that an upgrade that I have to unlock? I don't have an option to set workers on security.

Comment: Yes, I don't remember what exactly unlocks it though.  Possibly some of the motivation upgrades in the center or by making real guns/swords?  I know I got it before I first made security robots.  Might be worth a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speed up a Security Disagreement with any country, simply hit <kbd>f12</kbd> and type `data.conq[x] = true` where [x] is a number 1-11. The numbers correspond to the regions as follows:

- 1. USA
- 2. Mexico
- 3. Canada
- 4. Central America
- 5. Europe
- 6. Asia
- 7. China
- 8. Africa
- 9. Antarctica
- 10. South America
- 11. Australia

So for USA specifically, you would do `data.conq1 = true`